# mypy error occurred when argument name is different from the one defined in typing.Protocol

Tags: python-3.x, protocols, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing

The following code first defines the protocol `Proto` and then define a function that takes a variable follows that protocol. Then define classes `A` and `B` that I thought both follows the protocol, although only the argument name of `B.__call__` is different from the protocol (in `Proto` it's `x` and in `B` it'S `y`).

After checking the following code by mypy the following error was given

```
main.py:20: error: Argument 1 to "func" has incompatible type "B"; expected "Proto"
```

It seems that, Protocol not only enforce the type but also the argument name. Is this intended behavior? Or something wrong with mypy?

```py
from typing import Protocol

class Proto(Protocol):

    def __call__(self, x: int) -> int:
        ...

def func(f: Proto):
    pass

class A:
    def __call__(self, x: int) -> int:
        return x

class B:
    def __call__(self, y: int) -> int:
        return y

func(A())
func(B())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call a `Proto` `p` as `p(0)` or `p(x=0)`. `B` doesn't satisfy the second. If you want `B` to be valid, you can force a positional argument

```
class Proto(Protocol):
    def __call__(self, x: int, /) -> int:
        ...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked. I looked https://peps.python.org/pep-0544/ but I couldn't find the explanation like that and actually it's my first time to see `/` syntax. Could you give me some source/documentation of the this?

Comment: @orematasaburo it's called a [positional-only parameter](https://peps.python.org/pep-0570/). It's fairly new

Answer (score 1):

*NOTE: this answer is here for those who need backwards compatibility: for python 3.8 and above, use positional-only arguments declaration.*

Alternatively you can use `__dunder_beginning` names to say "I do not care about the name - allow any". `mypy` supports it (documentation [here](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/protocols.html#callback-protocols)), and it is backed by [PEP484](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#positional-only-arguments). [Typeshed uses this syntax](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/main/stdlib/typing.pyi#L325), so it should be supported by all type checkers. This is backwards-compatible (posonly arguments were introduced in 3.8, and 3.7 is still alive) way to declare protocol not respecting argument names.

```
# example from docs above
from typing import Callable, TypeVar
from typing_extensions import Protocol

T = TypeVar('T')

class Copy(Protocol):
    def __call__(self, __origin: T) -> T: ...

copy_a: Callable[[T], T]
copy_b: Copy

copy_a = copy_b  # OK
copy_b = copy_a  # Also OK
```

```
# Your example
from typing import Protocol

class Proto(Protocol):
    def __call__(self, __x: int) -> int:  # Change here
        ...

def func(f: Proto):
    pass

class A:
    def __call__(self, x: int) -> int:
        return x

class B:
    def __call__(self, y: int) -> int:
        return y

func(A())
func(B())
```

And this [passes type checking](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=db9690cfedf528e19c125b4d41dcc6bb).

This is not applicable to `*args` and `**kwargs`, because their name is not taken into account anyway.